# AOP with custom annotation in Super class doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

custom annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```

custom annotation handler

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspectHandler {
    @Around("execution(@com.test.project.annotaion.CustomAnnotation * *(..)) && @annotation(customAnnotation)")
    public Object testAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, CustomAnnotation customAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        return result;
    }
}
```

super class

```
public class AbstractDAO {
     @CustomAnnotation
     protected int selectOne(Object params){
          // .... something
     }
}
```

sub class

```
public class SubDAO extends AbstractDAO {
    public int selectSub(Object params) {
         return selectOne(params);
    }
}
```

subclass `SubDAO` call SuperClass method `selectOne` but in `TestAspectHandler.class` doesn't call `testAnnotation(...)`

when i move `@CustomAnnotation` to subclass `selectSub(..)` method AspectHandler can get `joinPoint`

how to work with Custom annotation in super class protected method?

---

`added`

change `TestAspectHandler.testAnnotation(...) method`

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(customAnnotation)")
public Object testAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, CustomAnnotation customAnnotation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("TEST");
            return result;
}
```

but still doesn't work

so i chnage my `SubDAO` like under code

```
public class SubDAO extends AbstractDAO {
    @Autowired
    private AbstractDAO abstractDAO;
    public int selectSub(Object params) {
         return abstractDAO.selectOne(params);
    }
}
```

this is not the perfect solution but it work

---

- case 1 : call Super class method from subclass method doesn't work
- case 2 : make Super class instance and call from instance work

Comment: If you have already read my answer, please also read the edit/update. There is new information now.

Comment: Spring AOP works using proxies, only method calls into the object pass through the proxy, you are doing an internal method call, hence it doesn't pass through the proxy and as such AOP isn't applied. Next to that even if it would apply the actual method wouldn't be invoked, as your around aspect breaks that.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I hope that your DAO classes are actual Spring components, otherwise Spring AOP does not find them, only AspectJ could.

But at the core of it this is not a Spring or AspectJ problem. In Java, annotations on

- interfaces,
- other annotations or
- methods

are never inherited by

- implementing classes,
- classes using annotated annotations or
- overriding methods.

Annotation inheritance only works from classes onto subclasses, but only if the annotation type used in the superclass bears the meta annotation `@Inherited`, see [JDK JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html).

Because I have answered this question several times before, I have just documented the problem and also a workaround in [Emulate annotation inheritance for interfaces and methods with AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607015/emulate-annotation-inheritance-for-interfaces-and-methods).

---

**Update:** Sorry, I just inspected your code more thoroughly. You are not overriding the superclass's annotated method (at least your code does not show that you override method `selectOne`), so what I described above does not apply here. Your aspect should work. But maybe you just have a typo in the fully qualified class name `@com.test.project.annotaion.CustomAnnotation`: The `annotaion` (note the typo!) package name should probably rather be `annotation`. And as I said in my first sentence: The DAOs must be Spring `@Component`s.

And by the way: You can avoid that part of the pointcut altogether because you already bind the annotation to a parameter. Just use

```java
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(customAnnotation)")
```

Comment: thanks but `Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(customAnnotation)")` doesn't work :( read updated question

Comment: Then something is wrong with your Spring configuration. Are both DAOs really Spring components? As I said: Spring AOP does **not** work on POJOs.

Comment: yes both DAO is Spring components if theres are POJO can't use @Autowired

Comment: Your workaround does not make sense. Why use inheritance and then assign the parent object to a member? Find the root cause and solve the problem!

Comment: Your right. but really don't know why it doesn't work :(. case 2 is work but case 1 is not

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is that your spring bean proxy (every reference to a spring bean is actually a proxy which delegates to the bean instance)  creates JDK Dynamoc proxy (for class which implements at least 1 interface  or CGLib proxy) for your applied aspects. so when the selectSub method is invoked, it's already passed the spring bean delegation and the aspect cannot be applied.
if you want to get it work you will have to annotate the sub method as well.